# Application poor responsiveness in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, responsive-design

I am showing one MessageBox inside manipulationStarted event(or Tap Event ) of an image and that is causing App poor responsiveness when we perform store monitoring test in V2012.

Xaml Image control -

```
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="104" Margin="90,60,0,0" Grid.Row="1"  
        ManipulationStarted="Image_ManipulationStarted_1" 
        Source="Background.png"/ >
```

Event Code –

```
private void Image_ManipulationStarted_1(object sender, 
                                         ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    var m = MessageBox.Show("The file will be saved here.", "File Save", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        int temp = 10;
    }
}
```

When I perform "Automated tests" in open store test kit for above sample code, it is causing poor responsiveness  and that cause to certification failure when we upload app the the market place.   Here are the steps -

1. Right click on Application Name  in the solution explore in Visual Studio 2012
2. Open store test kit -> Automated test -> Start Windows Phone Analysis -> Select App Analysis -> Click on Start Session (App will start)
3. Application Will start running
4. Perform the Tap event on the image, MessageBox will appear and click OK.
5. Click on End Session (App Will Exit) in V2012.
6. The result of App Analysis will be shown in   Summary. In that summary  you can see the Red Line in front of Responsiveness means the application responsiveness is poor which causes certification failure.

My requirement is like that only. I have one image (As a Button) and on click i.e Tap i want to do  some operation.

Note – Build is targeted to WP7 but application is running on WP8 emulator.

Regards

Mukesh Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Putting up a modal dialog inside an event handler will lock up the calling thread until the dialog is dismissed. That may give poor responsiveness rating.

What you may want to try is to in the event handler just disable the image for manipulation and dispatching the MessageBox to a time after the event handler has returned, something like (the untested);

```
private void Image_ManipulationStarted_1(object sender, 
                                         ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    // <disable image manipulation here>
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        var m = MessageBox.Show("The file will be saved here.", 
                               "File Save", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            int temp = 10;
        }
        // <enable image manipulation again>
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above approach but did not work. Please let me know how we can disable image manipulation manually and one more question: Dose App Slow responsiveness causes app certification failure while we upload app to the market place.